# How can I generate reports form Azure SQL that does not slow the system down?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, report

I hope someone can give me advice or point me to some readings for this. I generate business reports for my team. We host a subscription website so we need to track several things sometimes on a daily basis.  A lot of sql queries are involved.The problem is querying a large volume information from the live database will slow or cause timeouts to our website.

My current solution requires me to run bcp scripts that copy new rows to a backup database, (that I use purely for reports) daily. Then I use an application I made to generate reports from there. The output is ultimately an excel file or several (for the benefit of the business teams, it's easier for them to read.) There several problems in my temporary solution though,

1. It only adds new rows. Updates to previous rows are not copied. and
2. It doesn't seem very efficient.

Is there another way to do this? My main concern is that the generation or the querying should not slow down our site.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three options for you, each of which could have various implementation methods. The first one is Azure SQL Data Sync Services, the second is the AS COPY COPY operation and the third is rides on top of a backup.

The [Sync Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/) are a good option if you need more real time reporting capability; meaning if you need to run your reports multiple times a day, at just about any time, and you need your data as real time as you can get it.  Sync Services could have a performance impact on your primary database because it runs based off of triggers, but with this option you can choose what to sync; in other words you can replicate a filtered set of data, which minimizes the performance impact. Then you can reports on the sync'ed database. Another important shortcoming of this approach is that you would end up maintaining a sync service; if your primary database schema changes, you may need to recreate some or all of the sync configuration.

The second option, [AS COPY OF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336274.aspx), is a simply database copy operation which essentially gives you a clone of your primary database. Depending on the size of the database, this could take some time, so testing is key. However, if you are performing a morning report for yesterday's activities and having the latest data is not as important, then you could run the AS COPY OF operation on a schedule after hours (or when the activity on your database is the lowest) and run your report on the secondary database. You may need to build a small script, or use third party tools to help you automate this. There would be little to no performance impact on your primary database. In addition, the AS COPY OF operation provides transactional consistency, if this important to you.

The third option could be to use a backup mechanism (such as the [Azure Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh335292.aspx), or Azure backup tools), and restore the latest backup before running your reports. This has the advantage to leverage your backup strategy without much additional effort.